# Approximation in Frobenius norm by low rank matrices

Tags: optimization, matrix-equations

I am trying to optimize the following matrix function

$\min_{H,V}$ $\|A-HV\|_F^2$

under the following constraints
(1) $H$ is low rank 
(2) $V$ is positive (all entries of $V$ are non-negative)

Any pointers will be welcome ??

- can I alternate between solving for $H$ and $V$
- fix $H$ and solve for $V$ and then vice-versa

Comment: Note that $HV $ will also be of low rank, so the approximation cannot be better than the best approximation of low rank.  Further, we can take $V $ to be the identity so these problems have a common solution.

Comment: thanks hardmath for that insight !!

Comment: Is the [basic approximation by low rank matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Basic_low-rank_approximation_problem) in Frobenius norm familiar to you?